# height not matching - buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I want three buttons equally spaced and equally sized. when the text of one of the button is more than 3 words (new line), the button drops below as shown in picture. Is there a way to fix the same where in all the three buttons are in the same line? I tried using the `TableLayout`/`Row` but it did not help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <Button android:text="Trade"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_width="0dip" ></Button>
            <Button android:text="Set Alert"![enter image description here][2]                  
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip" ></Button>
            <Button android:text="Add to watchlist"                 
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dip"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see the picture you mentioned. Did you forget to add the link? Would be very helpful, I can't figure out what you want to do exactly from the text alone.

Comment: Missed adding the picture earlier. Its there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that, and it works for me when I take your above layout and set the android:layout_height to "fill_parent" on the 3 buttons.

(Though this is an interesting issue, not sure why that last button is a bit offset.)

Answer (score -1):

If you want the lines of the button to be no smaller/larger than a specific amount, you could try:

```
Button b = null;
b.setMaxLines(1);
b.setMinLines(1);
```

**UPDATE:**

b.setSingleLine();

Comment: this removes the content of the second line..i am looking to have all the buttons in one straight line..